# How to clean up session after server crash for connected clients via websocket?

Tags: node.js, session, websocket

- User enters credentials and login
- User connects via websocket and connection is paired with session
- User exits web browser and websocket connection is deleted
- Server update user status as unavailable
- User comes back, due to persistent session gets logged in
- Websocket new connection starts up, user is found and is paired again.

Problem starts

- User connects, status is set to available
- Server crashes for whatever reason
- Although websocket connection is broken to user, he is still marked as online. whereas he should be offline because..
- Server restarted and lost all sessions, meaning can't know who was logged in. meaning anyone 'online' is automatically signed out
- But since server crashed webserver on disconnect code never runs.
- upon new connection websocket sees user as unauthenticated user and does nothing. (as in dont mark it online as it can't since it doesn't know who the user is.)

how do I fix this.

Comment: Use a [persistent session store](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores) so sessions _don't_ get lost?

Comment: When user connects after server restarts, why is the user seen as unauthenticated?  That's your problem right there.  You should either force the user to reauthenticate or use a persistent session store so sessions are restored when server restarts.